# layout architecture :Header plus ViewPager using tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i want to do as per image . so basically

1. screen -
   full area is scrollable . top is layout where horizontal scroll is present . below that Tab layout and view pager

   2.Screen -
   when user scroll down then header part which is horizontal scroll will go (up not visible) and tab layout will be sticky header it always at top and only his view pager is swappable .but when again he  scroll  up then top header should come

i am ref this https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager but its not as per my need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this library:

https://github.com/noties/Scrollable

I think it's what you want.

Comment: in this can we hide toolbar when user swipe and tablayout as a sticky header

Comment: @andro you can try CoordinatorLayout  if you need this kind of effect.

Answer (score 0):

activity_tab_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
                <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"-->
                <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
                  <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">-->

                <!--</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </HorizontalScrollView>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

ActivityCode.java

```
public class ActivityCode extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cancer_type);

// your find view by id code

        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Fragment facts = new FRAGMENT_CLASS();
        adapter.addFragment(facts, "Title");
    Fragment facts = new FRAGMENT_CLASS();
        adapter.addFragment(facts, "Title");
    Fragment facts = new FRAGMENT_CLASS();
        adapter.addFragment(facts, "Title");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @andro you should compile  appcompatv7 and android design library.